# Strange behaviour with jQuery animation

Tags: jquery

I have a simple animation:

```
$(function () {
    $(".galleryButtonLeft").mousedown(function(){
        $("#theGallery").animate({ 
              marginLeft: "-=300px",
        }, 1000 );
    });
});
```

theGallery is just a `div` with `position:relative`.

Nothing fancy:

```
         <div style="position:relative">
              <img/>
         </div>
```

When I click my galleryButtonLeft to move it `300px` to the left, the page immediately goes to the top if I have my browser unmaximized and scroll to the middle of the page where my gallery sits. I want the page to stay where it is and not jump to the top everytime the button is clicked. How do I do that?

Comment: Side issue:  You have a trailing comma after the `300px` which is going to cause errors in certain versions of IE.

Comment: You should also provide the HTML code for the relevant bits.

Comment: You likely have an `href="#"` inside your button, which when clicked, will take you back to the top of the page.  See answer by @gion_13 below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that the `.galleryButtonLeft` element(s) is/are links with their `href` attribute set to a hash (`#`). Either `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the default behavior of the link(s):

```
$(function () {
    $(".galleryButtonLeft").mousedown(function(){
        $("#theGallery").animate({ 
            marginLeft: "-=300px"//notice I removed the trailing comma here, it'll come back to haunt you if you don't (some browsers throw errors for these)
        }, 1000 );
     }).click(false);//this returns false for any click event for the/these element(s), stopping the default behavior of the element(s)
});
```

Returning `false` inside of a jQuery event handler is the same thing as calling `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`.

If you want to use `event.preventDefault()` instead of returning `false` then you have to pass-in the `event` object in your anonymous function (event handler):

```
$(function () {
    $(".galleryButtonLeft").mousedown(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#theGallery").animate({ 
            marginLeft: "-=300px"//notice I removed the trailing comma here, it'll come back to haunt you if you don't (some browsers throw errors for these)
        }, 1000 );
    }).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Notice that you can call `event.preventDefault()` anywhere in the event handler, however returning `false` has to be the last thing called because it will stop the execution of the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

how about adding

```
/*...*/mousedown(function(e){e.preventDefault(); /*...*/
```

or

```
$(".galleryButtonLeft").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

I think that the problem might be that your trigger (`.galleryButtonLeft`) is an **a** element which has the `href` property set to something starting with `#`.This way, when you click the link, the hash in the browser bar changes, making the browser to jump up.